# What happens with multiple css blocks, using the same selector, defining the same properties, with different values?

Tags: css, selector

Example:

```
#mainContainer {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#mainContainer {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

It seems that the 2nd block overwrites the first, and the size will be 15px. Is this going to be consistent across browsers/selectors/css-properties?

Comment: In the case of using an identical selector like this, the one that executes last will take top priority. You can rely on that pretty consistently. But note that if the top rule had more hierarchy (like `#wrapper #mainContainer`) or an `!important`, it would override the bottom rule.

Answer (score 0):

The font will be 15 px. That is because CSS uses the latest defined value. Even when assigning different properties in the same selection, it will use the last assignment, here blue will be used:

```
.test { color: red; color: blue; }
```

Comment: `uses the latest defined value` --> we consider specificity first then if equal we consider ordre

Comment: you said `That is because CSS uses the latest defined value` which is not true ... because we first consider specificty/priority of the selector and the rule THEN if both are equal [like in this case] we consider the order ... so it's not always the latest defined one